# Access denied when using JSFORCE to connect and update records

Tags: soap-api, soap, jsforce

we've developed an ecommerce website for a client and want to integrate with their salesforce to add opportunities when a potential client creates an order on the website.

We had everything working in a sandbox environment but now that we're trying to switch to production we keep getting an error when trying to connect to the SOAP API.

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;salesforce&#46;com&#47;services&#47;Soap&#47;u&#47;42&#46;0" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;400c045...
```

Here's the connection code:

```
const jsforce = require("jsforce");

for (const variable of [
  "SALESFORCE_SECURITY_TOKEN",
  "SALESFORCE_USERNAME",
  "SALESFORCE_PASSWORD",
]) {
  if (!process.env[variable]) {
    throw `Environment variable ${variable} must be defined`;
  }
}

module.exports = {
  async login() {
    const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
      loginUrl: "https://salesforce.com",
    });

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      conn.login(
        process.env.SALESFORCE_USERNAME,
        process.env.SALESFORCE_PASSWORD + process.env.SALESFORCE_SECURITY_TOKEN,
        function (err) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve();
          }
        }
      );
    });

    return conn;
  },
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`loginUrl` should be either `https://test.salesforce.com` (sandboxes) or `https://login.salesforce.com` (production)